# C# Dependency Properties - Whether to Check Value in CLR Wrapper

Tags: c#, optimization, binding, dependency-properties

On writing custom dependency proerties in C#, a fairly common wrapper goes something like:

```
    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(SurnameProperty) as string;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(SurnameProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Now, when using the NotifyPropertyChanged system, I would normally check whether a value has changed in the 'set' block before actually committing the value and calling OnPropertyChanged. Should I do the same for dependency properties? i.e.:

```
        set
        {
            if(this.GetValue(SurnameProperty) != value)
               this.SetValue(SurnameProperty, value);
        }
```

...or is this something that is completely unnecessary and already taken care of by the CLR? All examples on MSDN that I have seen to not bother to do any checking before calling SetValue. Many thanks.

Comment: your getter/setter may not always be called. WPF will directly try to set the values.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! In my case, there are some times when I am also setting the values via the CLR wrappers rather than through binding, so the question really relates to this situation. Nevertheless, it doesn't do any harm to think about how dependencyproperties really work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no it's taken care by the framework already.

Actually, according to Adam Nathan's "Windows Presentation Foundation", XAML compiler depends on the property warpper at compile time.  However, .NET property wrappers are actually bypassed at run-time in XAML.  Therefore, you should actually avoid adding any kinds of logic in addtion to GetValue/SetValue.  Whatever logic you added in the setter is only executed if you call the property explicitly.  However, if you bind that property in XAML, the runtime will skip it.  If you have a bug in your setter, this may take you some time to figure out. Please see page 53 if you got that book in your hand.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like a book I need to take a look at!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's taken care of by the dependency property system.

Answer (score 0):

It is taken care by the property changed callback. The `PropertyChangedCallback` is called only when there is a change in the property value.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDependencyProperty =
                   DependencyProperty.Register(
                         "Dependency",
                          typeof(string),
                          typeof(MyUserControl),
                          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Initializing...", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyDependencyChangedCallBack)));
```